# Can the VideoWriter object in EMGU CV be used from within a Windows console application?

Tags: windows, opencv, mp4, emgucv

I've been using the VideoCapture class to read frames from an MPEG4 file, make some modifications to the frames, then write them out to a new MPEG4 file using the VideoWriter class.
This works fine from within a WPF and Winforms app, but when I attempt to call the same code from within a simple console app, the creation of the VideoWriter object throws and exception.

```
int fourcc = VideoWriter.Fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V');
using (var videoWriter1 = new VideoWriter("C:\\temp\\output.mp4, fourcc, 30, outputSize, true))
{
    ....
}
```

Exception Message : "Unable to create VideoWriter. Make sure you have the specific codec installed"

This is the same no matter what fourcc code I pass in.

Does anyone know why the VideoWriter cannot be used in a Windows console app?

Using EMGU 4.1.0.4320 with VS2017 on Windows 10